# Node Js avoid worker threads to serve web application

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js, nestjs, vite

I am trying to build and serve nuxt app (internally it uses vitejs to serve) from NestJS dynamically.

Currently I am doing it as below. Using H3.

```
const { loadNuxt, buildNuxt } = await import('@nuxt/kit');

const nuxt = await loadNuxt({
  rootDir: config.rootDir,
  dev: true
  dotenv: {
    cwd: config.rootDir,
  },
});

const nuxt = await buildNuxt(nuxt);

const { toNodeListener } = await import('h3');
const currentHandler = toNodeListener(nuxt.server.app);
await currentHandler(req, res);
```

H3 is running using Worker Thread to server request. One of my library (I am using fabric.js which internally uses canvas.js) is not supported by worker thread. So I am getting error as below.

```
[worker reload] Error: Module did not self-register: '\\?\C:\Projects\GitLab\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node'.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1338:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\GitLab\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
```

How can I avoid worker thread, so that I can serve app from main thread only to avoid this error?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is second most painful area of all my career.